# Datarow maintains DBNull, even after removing it

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, datatable

I'm at my last resort, clueless and lost!

For a synchronization project at work I have to translate data from our database to Dynamics NAV records in a generic manner.

The database at work is old and contains a mixture of empty fields("") and NULL's which both mean the same. To perform the translation in a generic manner I'd like to remove all DBNull's from the data I retrieve, and replace them with their default(chosen by me) equivalent value.

Since the data is quite big and the translation quite a heavy operation i'm performing the translation multithreaded, but more on that later.

At a moment in time I do this after retrieving my data:

```
'...
Using DT As DataTable = ODB.DataTable(sql)

    CurrentRecordSet = DT.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).ToList()
    CurrentRecordSet.ForEach(Sub(DR) RemoveDBNull(DR))

End Using
'...
```

As for RemoveDBNull, this just works a little like the Field(Of T) method of DataSetExtensions(In fact it uses it):

```
Public Sub RemoveDBNull(ByRef DR As DataRow)
    For Each Col As DataColumn In DR.Table.Columns
        Dim ColDataType As Type = Col.DataType
        Dim currentValue As Object
        Dim NewValue As Object
        Dim FieldMethod As Reflection.MethodInfo = GetType(DataRowExtensions).GetMethod("Field", {GetType(DataRow), GetType(String)})
        If ColDataType.IsValueType Then
            Dim NullableColDataType As Type = GetType(Nullable(Of)).MakeGenericType(ColDataType)
            currentValue = FieldMethod.MakeGenericMethod(NullableColDataType).Invoke(Nothing, {DR, Col.ColumnName})
            If IsNothing(currentValue) Then
                NewValue = Activator.CreateInstance(ColDataType)
            Else
                NewValue = currentValue
            End If
        Else
            currentValue = FieldMethod.MakeGenericMethod(ColDataType).Invoke(Nothing, {DR, Col.ColumnName})
            If IsNothing(currentValue) AndAlso ColDataType Is GetType(String) Then
                NewValue = String.Empty
            ElseIf currentValue IsNot Nothing Then
                NewValue = currentValue
            End If
        End If
        DR(Col) = NewValue
    Next
End Sub
```

And at last the multithreaded translate call:

```
Private Sub PerformSyncTranslation(ByVal SyncType As String, ByVal TargetEntityType As String, ByRef dicEcDependencies As Dictionary(Of String, EntityCollection))
    Try
        Dim localdep = dicEcDependencies
        Parallel.ForEach(CurrentRecordSet, Sub(dr As DataRow)
                                               ecLocal.Add(dr.ToEntity(TargetEntityType, localdep, ecRetrieve.FirstOrDefault(Function(e) e(Cache.GetPrimaryKey(TargetEntityType)) = dr(SyncType))))
                                           End Sub)
        dicEcDependencies = localdep
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw 'Don't mind this, debugging purposes only
    End Try
End Sub
```

Now I know for a fact, that all the records in fact get processed by RemoveDBNull, and it does it very well, and surprisingly fast despite the Reflection.
Yet still inside ToEntity() I see that some of my datarows have their DBNull values again.

I am clueless about why this happens. I know DataTables are not threadsafe, that's why I remove the nulls and store the datarows seperately single threaded, before performing multithreaded operations on them.

Hope I've been specific enough...

Thanks
Anton